# why style is not geting applied to text in html

Tags: html, css

I have applied style to  element. But somehow it is getting applied for the first reload. When go to another page and come back  same style not getting applied.

[image]

For the first page load above style got applied to element. When I come to same page after visiting another page, above style not applied to same element.

I'm not getting what went wrong.

I'm able to see style to element but not reflecting in UI.

what went wrong. Kindly suggest.

my HTML and CSS is below

```
<div style=display:block;width:100%;height:350px;overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;>
    <div class=abc>
        <div style=padding-top:10px;font-size:12px;font-family:SegoeUI;margin-left:10px;width:302px;height:38px;padding-top:8px>Text 1
        </div>
        <table style=margin-left:10px;margin-top:30px;>
            <tbody>
            <tr style=width:360px;height:23px;padding-top:9px>
                <td style=font-size:12px; font-family:Segoe UI Semibold>Header 1</td>
                <td style=width:15px;background:#FDFFFF;></td>
                <td style=font-size:12px;font-family:Segoe UI Semibold>Header 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style=width:360px;height:23px>
                <td style=padding-left:10px;font-size:12px;font-family:SegoeUI;background:#EAFBFB;>Text 2</td>
                <td style=width:15px;background:#FDFFFF;></td>
                <td style=font-size:12px;font-family:Segoe UI;>Text 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style=Height:4px;background:white></tr>
            <tr style=Height:4px;background:white></tr>
            <tr style=width:360px;height:56px>
                <td style=padding-left:10px;font-size:12px;font-family:SegoeUI;background:#EAFBFB;>Text 4</td>
                <td style=width:15px;background:#FDFFFF;></td>
                <td style=width:177px;height:51px;font-size:12px;font-family:Segoe UI>Text 5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style=Height:4px;background:white></tr>
            <tr style=width:360px;height:45px>
                <td style=padding-left:10px;font-size:12px;font-family:SegoeUI;background:#EAFBFB;width:134px;height:32px>
                    Text 6
                </td>
                <td style=width:15px;background:#FDFFFF;></td>
                <td style=width:166px;height:35px;font-size:12px;font-family:Segoe UI;width:166px;height:35px>Text 7
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style=Height:4px;background:white></tr>
            <tr style=Height:4px;background:white></tr>
            <tr style=width:360px;height:44.29px>
                <td style=padding-left:10px;font-size:12px;font-family:SegoeUI;background:#EAFBFB;>Text 8</td>
                <td style=width:15px;background:#FDFFFF;></td>
                <td style=height:33.84px;width:173px;font-size:12px;font-family:Segoe UI>Text 9</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

tried `!important` but still not working.

Comment: You might be having same class declared in the another page. 
Also check for classes declared with `!important`, they might be overriding this.

Comment: some other css overriding it. more specific with `!important` syntax

Comment: why not use css inline and check

Comment: Share HTML and CSS code.

Comment: please add a double quote to your style ex: **style="color:red;"**

Answer (score 1):

Try to use correct format for the inline CSS rules. EX: style="font-size: 10px, font-family: 'Segoe UI'"

```html
<div style="display:block;width:100%;height:350px;overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden;">
 <div class=abc><div style="padding-top:10px;font-size:12px;font-family:'Segoe UI';margin-left:10px;width:302px;height:38px;padding-top:8px">Text 1</div>
 <table style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:30px;">
  <tbody>
   <tr style="width:360px;height:23px;padding-top:9px">
    <td style="font-size:12px; font-family:'Segoe UI Semibold';">Header 1</td>
    <td style=width:15px;background:#FDFFFF;></td>
    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:'Segoe UI Semibold'">Header 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style=width:360px;height:23px>
    <td style="padding-left:10px;font-size:12px;font-family:'SegoeUI';background:#EAFBFB;">Text 2</td>
    <td style=width:15px;background:#FDFFFF;></td>
    <td style="font-size:12px;font-family:'Segoe UI';">Text 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style=Height:4px;background:white></tr>
   <tr style=Height:4px;background:white></tr>
   <tr style=width:360px;height:56px>
    <td style="padding-left:10px;font-size:12px;font-family:'SegoeUI';background:#EAFBFB;">Text 4</td>
    <td style=width:15px;background:#FDFFFF;></td>
    <td style="width:177px;height:51px;font-size:12px;font-family:'Segoe UI';">Text 5</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style=Height:4px;background:white></tr>
   <tr style=width:360px;height:45px>
    <td style="padding-left:10px;font-size:12px;font-family:'SegoeUI';background:#EAFBFB;width:134px;height:32px">Text 6</td>
    <td style=width:15px;background:#FDFFFF;></td>
    <td style="width:166px;height:35px;font-size:12px;font-family:'Segoe UI';width:166px;height:35px">Text 7</td>
   </tr>
   <tr style=Height:4px;background:white></tr>
   <tr style=Height:4px;background:white></tr>
   <tr style=width:360px;height:44.29px>
    <td style="padding-left:10px;font-size:12px;font-family:'SegoeUI';background:#EAFBFB;">Text 8</td>
    <td style=width:15px;background:#FDFFFF;></td>
    <td style="height:33.84px;width:173px;font-size:12px;font-family:'Segoe UI';">Text 9</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

That is because some other css is applied. you need to say as **!important** at the  end of css.

```
.custom-class{
    font-size: 22px !important;
}
```

Comment: Following CSS specificity rules is a much better approach than the sledgehammer that is `!important`